# Fastest approach to finding the most common first and second value of tuples in an N-dimensional array of tuples in Python

Tags: python, performance, multidimensional-array

I have M number of N-dimensional arrays of tuples and I'd like to find most frequent value in the first elements of the tuples and the second elements, here's a single N-dimen array demo data:

```
data = [[(2, 0), (0, 3), (0, 2), (0, 3), (2, 4), (0, 3), (0, 3), (2, 7)],
        [(2, 0), (0, 1), (2, 0), (0, 1), (3, 4), (2, 7), (2, 0), (2, 7)],
        [(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2)],
        [(2, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (2, 1), (2, 1)]]
```

Here's my current implementation:

```
from collections import Counter


def find_most_common_values(data):
# Flatten the n-dimensional array
    flattened = []
    for sublist in data:
        for item in sublist:
            flattened.append(item)

    # Separate the elements
    x = [item[0] for item in flattened]
    y = [item[1] for item in flattened]

    c = Counter(x)
    most_common_x = c.most_common(1)[0][0]
    c = Counter(y)
    most_common_y = c.most_common(1)[0][0]

    return most_common_x, most_common_y

# Demo function
def main():
    data = [[(2, 0), (0, 3), (0, 2), (0, 3), (2, 4), (0, 3), (0, 3), (2, 7)],
            [(2, 0), (0, 1), (2, 0), (0, 1), (3, 4), (2, 7), (2, 0), (2, 7)],
            [(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2)],
            [(2, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (2, 1), (2, 1)]]

    most_common_x, most_common_y = find_most_common_values(data)
    print("Most commont X: " + str(most_common_x))
    print("Most commont Y: " + str(most_common_y))



# Main entry point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which correctly outputs the following:

```
Most commont X: 2
Most commont Y: 3
```

Since I'm going to utilize this in a for loop with a lot of data I'm trying to implement the fastest approach and since I'm a newbie in Python I guess there are better ways I'm not aware of, so anyone know a faster approach preferably more Pythonic?

Comment: FWIW, this _might_ be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner to achieve this using `collections.Counter` along with `zip` and `itertools.chain` in *list comprehension*:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

a, b = [Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0] for x in zip(*chain(*data))]
```

Output:

```
>>> a
2
>>> b
3
```

You can refer below documents to read more about these functions:

- ["iterools.chain()" dcoumentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)
- ["zip" documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- ["collections.Counter()" documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: I love one-liners! Thank you! :D